# Choosing the correct shard key for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, primary-key, sharding

I'm new to MongoDB. From the mongod documentation, I know that when choosing shard keys the key should always have high cardinality, so write operations are distributed to different shards (a kind of write scaling). But for query isolation, better query performance will be gained if a query is routed to a single shard server (one single mongos instance).

I need recommendations or guidance on choosing the right shard key based on the JSON data below. My plan is to store the below JSON as one row in the MongoDB collection. `ReceiptID` is unique for each row, but most of the queries will be on `RetailerID`. `RetailerID` is not unique for each row and will be the same for each row. I can use `ReceiptID` as the shard key which has high cardinality and provides better write scaling. But having an index on this field is not helpful since most of my queries will be on `RetailerID` but `RetailerID` won't be unique for each row. Should I use a compound index (`RetailerID` + `timestamp`) as the shard key?

Any guidance or recommendations for choosing the correct shard key?

```
{
  "RetailerID": 2,
  "RetailerName": "Walmart",
  "RetailerLogo": "",
  "RetailerAddress": "yyututiu",
  "RetailerPublicKey": "yutuytytyu",
  "Consumer_id": "1",
   "ReceiptsData": {
    "ReceiptID": 2,
    "order_date": "2017-03-03 18:36:57",        
    "total": "39.40",
    "billing_name": "AJ Test",
    "shippingAddress": "35 seconf Street, Moscow, PA, 18444\r\n",
    "cc_brand": "MC",
    "cc_last_4": 9902,
    "ItemDetails": [
      {
        "itemname": "Benj Moore Paintyy",
        "UPC": "12726600",
        "itemPrice": "15.00",
        "qty": "1.00",                     
        "datetime": "2017-03-03 18:36:57"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "Test Item",
        "UPC": "12726600",
        "itemPrice": "15.00",
        "qty": "1.00",            
        "datetime": "2017-03-03 18:36:57"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```